# Graph API 2.5 - some endpoints exist but require deprecated permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions, facebook-rest-api

I'm wondering what is the reason that in Grap API v2.5 reference there are still listed endpoints which require deprecated permissions? For example:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/home - which requires `read_stream` already deprecated in v2.4 and not available in v2.5

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/inbox - 
which requires `read_mailbox` which is also deprecated...

Is it possible to continue using these endpoints? I have been trying to use user/home but it fails... and I can't find any alternative.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There are no alternatives – you can not access /home nor their messages any more. The most you can do, is get [`/{user-id}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#read)

Answer (score 2):

The docs are not always up to date, the changelog is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

If it says that `read_stream` and `read_mailbox` are deprecated, then that´s how it is. You need to use `/me/feed` now, and you can only get your own entries (and those of friends on your own wall).